# Linux Fork Process termination

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe, fork

```
//Executing shell command ls -l | sort
int *pipeIN, *pipeOUT;

int runLS(){
    char* parmListLS[] = { "ls", "-l", NULL };
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid==0){
        close(*pipeIN);
        dup2(*pipeOUT, STDOUT_FILENO);
        execvp(parmListLS[0], parmListLS);
    }else return pid;
}

int runSORT(){
    char* parmListSORT[] = { "sort", NULL };
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid==0){
        close(*pipeOUT);
        dup2(*pipeIN, STDIN_FILENO);
        execvp(parmListSORT[0], parmListSORT);
    }else return pid;
}

int main(void){
    int pidLS, pidSort, pipeId[2];
    pipeIN = &pipeId[0], pipeOUT = &pipeId[1];
    pipe(pipeId); //open pipes

    pidLS = runLS();
    pidSort = runSORT();

    printf("PIDS: LS -> %d, Sort -> %d\n", pidLS, pidSort);
    printf("Terminated: %d\n", wait(NULL)); //return pid of 1st exited proc
    printf("Terminated: %d\n", wait(NULL)); //return pid of 2nd exited proc
    printf("Terminated Main Proccess!\n");
}
```

Hello! I'm having trouble making some simple pipes work on linux.
I'm trying to emulate the shell command ls - l | sort.
As you can see, I'm initializing two child proccesses,
one for ls -l, and the other for sort.
Those proccesses run independently, and I'm trying to redirect the output
of ls - l, as input for sort via pipes. The concept is that the main program
should wait for both of them to terminate. However, wait seems to work
fine for ls -l, but it hangs - never terminates for sort. So the whole program
hangs. If I remove the two wait code lines from the program, the ls - l -> sort
pipe works perfectly, and of course main terminates before them.
I suspect this is due to the fact that sort keeps waiting for input,
even after ls - l has terminated. I don't understand how the termination of
the parent affects the termination of both children processes.
Would anyone please be so kind as to explain to me what actualy happens?
Thank you very much. ps. I ignored most error checking for clarity and less code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sort` can't terminate because the parent process still has the write end (and the read end) of the pipe open, so the `sort` hasn't reached EOF on the pipe, so it hasn't got all the data, so it can't write any output.

Add:

```
close(pipeId[0]);
close(pipeID[1]);
```

after the calls to `runLS()` and `runSORT()` and things work as expected.

Ideally, the children should close both ends of the pipe after they've just duplicated.  If you duplicate a pipe file descriptor to a standard file stream, you should almost always close *both* ends of the pipe.  In this code, you get away without doing it; that won't always be the case.

Personally, I don't think the two global variables help much.  The pipe labelled `pipeIn` is the input to `sort` but the output from `ls`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your support, indeed your approach works.
Could you explain a bit more your part of the answer [Ideally...be the case]? How could I possibly close the ends of the pipe in the above code?
As for the variables, indeed I almost never have globals anyway, it was just for clarity.

Comment: After the call to `dup2(*pipeOUT, STDOUT_FILENO);`, you have two file descriptors open for the write end of the pipe in the `ls` child; one is the value in `*pipeOUT`, the other `STDOUT_FILENO`.  You really aren't going to use the `*pipeOUT` descriptor again, so you should now close it.  Similarly with the `dup2()` in the `sort` child.  And you can also argue that the parent isn't going to use either end of the pipe so it should close those file descriptors on those grounds too.  Making sure you have enough close calls is surprisingly often the trick to getting pipe-based programs to work.

Comment: And as to how you'd close it: `close(*pipeOUT)` and `close(*pipeIN)` in the children.  In fact, for symmetry, you'd do the `dup2()` and then the two closes in each child.  The `dup2()` calls are slightly different, but the closes are the same.

Comment: After a little bit more research based on your answers, I think I complitly understand now how file descriptors, dup and pipes work.
So thank you very much, and have a beautiful day :)